# Краш MySQL в XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

Пытаюсь запустить MySQL в XAMPP но она постоянно крашиться.

XAMPP log

```
11:37:46  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
11:37:46  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:37:46  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:37:46  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:37:46  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:37:46  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
11:37:46  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

mysql_error.log

```
2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1835027
2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown
```

Пробовал это исправить различными способами которые пишут в интернете, но ничего не помогает...
Пробовал: удалить файлы ibdata1, ib_logfile0 и тд, удалить файлы innodb_index_stats .frm и .ibd

Comment: Можно попробовать прямо указать в конфиге MySQL ip адрес (это настройка `bind-address` должна быть) `bind-address="127.0.0.1" `  `bind-address = ::1  # for ipv6`

Comment: @Eleferen , не помогло(